# $\Delta$-system Lemma to disprove existence of an uncountable antichain?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am trying answer a question:

> Let $\mathbb{P} = \{p \mid p \text{ is a finite function } \omega_2 \times \omega \to 2\}$ ordered by revesre inclusion, i.e. $p<q$ iff $p \supseteq q$. Does $\mathbb{P}$ have an uncountable antichain?

I know, that I'm supposed to use $\Delta$-system Lemma to deduce a negative answer:

> If $A$ is an uncountable system of finite subsets of $\omega_1$, then there exists an uncountable $\Delta$-subsystem $B \subseteq A$.

I understand that I need to work with domains of functions but I don't quite see how to continue. Hints are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is an uncountable subset of $\Bbb P$, then $\{\operatorname{dom}p\mid p\in D\}$ is an uncountable family of finite subsets of $\omega_2\times\omega$. So it contains an uncountable $\Delta$-system $A$ with a root $a$.

Now, given any two conditions in $D$ with domain in $A$, they are compatible if and only if they agree on their restriction to $a$. But since $a$ is finite, there can only be finitely many "types" and $\{p\in D\mid\operatorname{dom}p\in A\}$ is uncountable, so there is a "type" which is realised uncountably many times. In particular any two such conditions will be compatible.

Comment: You can prove this in a different way if you know a bit of model theory to have an understanding of elementary submodels, and a bit of set theory to know what's $H(\theta)$. You can find the proof in [my lecture notes](https://karagila.org/files/Forcing-2023.pdf) on pages 19 and 20.

Comment: The $\Delta$-system lemma is really just about about an uncountable family of finite sets. If it's uncountable, might as well assume it's of size $\aleph_1$, and then just fix a bijection with $\omega_1$ and the union of these sets. The word "isomorphism" is very loaded, and the context needs to be clear (isomorphism means preserving structure, but which structure are we talking about?). But in general, the only requirement is that we have uncountably many finite sets.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!